# Mount physical device via network

Tags: linux-networking, mount, network-storage

Is there a way on Linux based OS to mount a physical device e.g. `/dev/sdb` (which is located in a server) directly on a client?

Something like `mount user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/dev/sdb /mnt/my_local_folder`

I know there are plenty of options like, sshfs / nfs / cifs to share the content of a mounted partition between devices but I want to directly pass through a device via the network to simplify the process.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI

Comment: @IporSircer "In a nutshell, it provides block-level access to storage devices over a TCP/IP network." - Wikipedia, thank you very much, this is 100% what I was looking for!

Comment: Uhm... Regarding ISCSI keep in mind that it is not meant for multi host access, you need a higher protocol for that. ISCSI allows block level access but it doesn't provide any multiuser security measures like file locking by itself.

Comment: go with cifs/nfs as it is described http://superuser.com/questions/145191/how-do-i-map-a-drive-network-share-using-the-linux-terminal

Comment: You can also look at [nbd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nbd-server.1.html) which exports files or real block devices over the network where they can be used like any block device.